# Storefront header and footer

Tags: css, storefront

I am stuck. I have placed a image into the header of the storefront theme. After much experimenting I got the image to align with the contents of the header. I have made it 1280 px wide. I want a footer 1280px wide to be aligned vertically in the header. The CSS I have tried is

```
.site-footer {
width: 1280px;
float: centre;
}
```

This produces a footer, left adjusted :(

I know I am stupid but what am I missing here?

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: centre;` (or `float: center;`)

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` is what you're looking for.

Comment: That worked, thanks